# How do i merge a dataframe based off an address and longitude and latitude? Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have a csv davaset like this which i geocoded and added in the long lat columns, and it has these columns[image: My Dataset]

now i download an updated one online and it sometimes adds in new houses like this(i highlighted the wrong house, its supposed to be the one above it sorry :) 
  )
[image: Downloaded one]

and i want to merge the two data sets together and retain my longitude and latitude information and only keep the columns i have.  I cant seem to figure out how to do the merge so i manually wrote this python but its too slow

```
 for index, row in new_ppr.iterrows():
    address= row['Address']
    houses_in_district = MASTER_ppr.loc[MASTER_ppr['Address'] == address]
    if len(houses_in_district >= 1):
        x = houses_in_district.tail(1).index.item()
        new_ppr.loc[index, 'Longitude'] = houses_in_district.loc[x,'Longitude']
        new_ppr.loc[index, 'Latitude'] = houses_in_district.loc[x,'Latitude']
    else:
        new_ppr.loc[index, 'Longitude'] = ""
        new_ppr.loc[index, 'Latitude'] = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have primary indices in both tables, I think the easiest way is to use `pandas`, something similar to:

> ```
> import pandas as pd
> a = pd.read_csv('filename1.csv')
> b = pd.read_csv('filename2.csv')
>
> c = a.merge(b, how = 'left', left_on = 'INDEX IN A', right_on = 'INDEX IN B')
> ```
>
> You need to figure out the indices in each table based on which the merge will be performed. More details and examples can be found on [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)